# How do I convert a query builder code to Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

The code works, but some say it's a bad example, 
and it needs to be rewritten into a relationship, 
but I do not know how, can you tell?

Articles can be added to different categories

The "add Relation" method gets an array with the category values and article id

and after processing, this data is added to the intermediate table

```php
array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]

public function addRelation($categories, $id)
    {   
        $categoryId = [];
        $collection = collect($categories);
        $collection = $collection->chunk(1);

        $collection->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$categoryId, $id){
             $categoryId[] = [
                   'image_id' => $id,
                   'category_id' => $item->first()
                   ] ;
              }

          );

           DB::table('category_image')->insert($categoryId);
    }
```

---

deleting

```php
public function deleteImage($image)
    {    
      Storage::delete($image->image);
      $this->destroy($image->id);

      DB::table('category_image')->where('image_id', $image->id)->delete();
    }
```

---

Models

```php
class Image extends Model
{   

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}


class Category extends Model
{   
     protected $fillable = ['name'];
     public $timestamps = false;


     public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Services\Image');
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```php
Schema::create('category_image', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('image_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
        });


Schema::create('category_image', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('image_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
        });


Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
```

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir null $relation = \App\Services\Image::find($idNewImage);
        
      dd($relation->categories()->attach($categories));

Comment: `attach()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir When outputting a zero value, I looked through the database and there appeared new data, it turns out that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $rules = [
           'description' => 'min:4',
           'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
           'choose-category' => 'array|required'
           ];

        $messages = [
            'description.min' => 'Название должно содержать минимум :min символа.',
            'image.required' => 'Изображение загружать обязательно.',
            'image.image' => 'Вы загрузили не изображение.',
            'image.mimes' => 'Допустимые форматы: jpg, jpeg, png.',
            'choose-category.required' => 'Выберите категорию'
         ];

        Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            $rules ,
            $messages
              )->validate();

      $image = $request->file('image');

      $description = $request->input('description');

      $this->imageClass->add($image, $description);

      $this->imageClass->save();

      $idNewImage = $this->imageClass->id;
      $categories = $request->input('choose-category');

      $relation = \App\Services\Image::find($idNewImage);

      $relation->categories()->attach($categories);

      //$this->imageClass->addRelation($categories, $idNewImage);

      return redirect('/');
    }
```